# ComboBox with ArrayList

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to find all files with the *.xls* extension and print the names of the files into a combobox. When I run my program, the combobox is empty, but the debugger shows that the *files* arraylist has a count of 4.

This is what I have:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ArrayList files = new ArrayList();

    files.AddRange(System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("c:\\test", "*.xls"));

    comboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;

    foreach (int i in files)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(i);
    }

    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Comment: your code even doesn't compile

Comment: stop using darn `ArrayList` and use `List<T>`

Comment: @KingKing Why not? this will compile.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel my mistake, It's `ArrayList` which accepts any object interater, however it would throw invalid cast exception at runtime.

Comment: @KingKing Of course I've pointed it in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

**First**, your code is not working because `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles` doesn't return `integers` which you enumerated over in `foreach` loop.

**Second**,
If you want to keep your code, amend it as:

```
foreach (var i in files)
{
   comboBox1.Items.Add(i.ToString());
}
```

**Third**, you can write an elegant and more convenient code:

```
  var files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("c:\\test", "*.xls");
  comboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
  comboBox1.Items.AddRange(files);
  comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: Third one won't compile

Comment: @SriramSakthivel You sure? I'm on .Net 4. I just pasted it again and it compiles and works. Would you please report the compile error?

Comment: Yup, This will in 4.0 due to covariance. Earlier it won't

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    foreach (FileInfo file in files)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(file.Name);
    }
```

Comment: files is string[] not FileInfo[]

Comment: The link by `bland` shows that [GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx) returns an array of strings.

Comment: LOL - thanks, bland. I was just posting that. So `foreach (string file in files)` instead of `FileInfo`.

Answer (score 0):

```
     ArrayList files = new ArrayList();

    files.AddRange(System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("c:\\test", "*.xls"));

    comboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;

    foreach (string i in files)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(i);
    }

    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not used to ArrayList, but I believe it contains strings and not integers.

You should change your foreach to:

```
foreach(string file in files)
    comboBox1.Items.Add(i);
```

However, you could simply do this:

```
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles("C:\\test", "*.xls"));
```

Good luck with your quest.

Comment: Second one won't compile

Comment: did you remember using System.IO first in your source file?

Comment: I was talking about casting `string[]` to `object[]`. In .net4 this will compile due to covariance. earlier it wont

Comment: It compiles using Framework 2.0, that is as low VS 2012 can go.

Comment: Am not sure. If you're building in c# compiler 4.0 It allows you to make use of its features which is independent of CLR. like this. I've to agree that this works with c#4.0 compiler. If you have vs 2008 or lower you may try to see what I was talking about

Answer (score 0):

[Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx) returns an array of strings.  Not integers.  So you looped and found no items.

```
foreach (string file in files)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add(file);
}
```